# Cancel local notification

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I want to list scheduled local notifications in order to check fired date, to cancel the good one.

This is how I'm adding local notifications :

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.fireDate = date
notification.alertBody = message
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
```

This is how I'm listing all notification to find the good one :

```
for oneEvent in UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications! {
    if date == notification.fireDate {
        app.cancelLocalNotification(notification)
    }
}
```

Problem is that I create a lot of notifications and there are always only one notification in `scheduledLocalNotifications` !

Notification are fired correctly but I can't retrieve them is `scheduledLocalNotifications` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am not getting your question but i have some doubt in bellow code try this:

you must write this line after creating notification.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

then

```
for oneEvent in UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications! {
    if date == oneEvent.fireDate {
         app.cancelLocalNotification(oneEvent)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i'm doing. I can add 10 notifications, scheduledLocalNotifications will always contains only one notification. Very strange behavior

Comment: 10 notifications with different  fire date?

Comment: yes ! notifications are fired with no problem, but I can't cancel them like I would to

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ios 10 you can try importing UserNotifications framework (UserNotifications.framework) and then

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.getPendingNotificationRequests(...)
```

In IOS 10, Apple moved to the new Notification framework, you can still create and schedule local notifications using the old way ( sharedApplication.scheduleLocalNotification) but there will be strange behaviors when you handle them the old way (UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications).